# how to embed icon in a link anchor text of rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate this code with the help of ROR:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-area-chart"></i>
  <span class="nav-link-text">Charts</span>
</a>
```

I tried this:

```html
<%= link_to charts_path, class: 'nav-link' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-area-chart"></i>  
  <span class="nav-link-text">Charts</span>
 <% end %>
```

But Icon is not appearing, everything is fine. **How to get icon to display?**

Comment: That code should work, whats the generated html for the `link_to`?

Comment: What about [font-awesome-rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails)?

Comment: font awesome rails gem is included in app and working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `icon` helper.

```
<%= link_to charts_path, class: 'nav-link' do %>
  <%= icon('area-chart', class: 'fw') %>
  <span class="nav-link-text">Charts</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is doing nothing